# drop columns that take less than n values?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose i have a data frame like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T), v2 = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T),
                 V3 = sample(letters, 100, replace = T), v4 = sample(1:15, 100, replace = T))
```

I would like to create a new data frame df2 only includes the columns that take more than 10 values. So, in this example it would be v2, v3, and v4. How can I do that? In practice my data frame has thousands of columns.

I tried this:

```
df2 <- df %>% select(which(length(unique(.))>10))
```

Comment: `df[, sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x))) > 10]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `select_if()` from `dplyr` where you can pass a function as predicate to select columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select_if(function(col) n_distinct(col) > 10)

#    v2 V3 v4
#1    T  a 12
#2    R  k  7
#3    L  l  1
# ...
```

---

Or using `select` with `where` in `dplyr` version `>=1.00`

```
df  %>%
     select(where(~ n_distinct(.) > 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Clunky but it works...

```
x<-as.data.frame(t(apply(df,2,function(x) length(x[unique(x)]))>10))

df[,names(x[,x>0])]
```

Comment: It works. There are better solutions, but to denigrate the time spent for a working solution without even posting why is crappy.  Do better SE.